# Gravatar Problems?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

Is anyone else experiencing the following problem today with Stack Overflow:  When I refresh my page (Questions tagged 'java') the page loads but the browser loading icon continues to animate with the status message "Waiting for www.gravatar.com...".  However, as far as I can see all page content has already loaded.

(I'm running Firefox 3.5.7.)

**UPDATE**

Update: Tried flushing my browser cache but it didn't help but restarting Firefox fixed the problem.  Weird thing is it only happened if I searched for Questions tagged with "java" (sounds bizarre I know) and viewed the "Newest" tab.  If I searched for multiple tags (but including java) everything was ok.  Also, it looked like my browser isn't waiting on gravatar.com consistently; It was also waiting on ads.stackoverflow.com (and also google-analytics.com some of the time).  Anyway, not a big deal (obviously) - Just weird.

Comment: I haven't seen anything out of the ordinary when it comes to gravatars, no.

Comment: Works on my machine.

Comment: Gravatar is NOT working on StackExchange Sites. Can anyone confirm? After i changed my EMAIL to GMAIL on my GRAVATAR and STACK profile, no more gravatar (done that over a MONTH now!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this a lot between 00:00 and 09:00 GMT today (Feb 9, 2010). A traceroute to Gravatar showed some gnarly looking packet loss at one of the transit providers between my ISP and Gravatar. I also saw the SO Google Analytics domain exhibiting the same problems.

I'm putting it down to run-of-the-mill upstream TCP/IP congestion.

Answer (score 2):

If your browser is hanging waiting for Gravatar then really it's between you and Gravatar, SO's not to blame.  Flush your browser cache and try it again, see if that helps.  If not, then you've got something going on preventing communication with Gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.

No problems with Gravatar here - flushed the cache, reload SO, and it still loads very, very quickly.

Comment: Gravatar is NOT working on StackExchange Sites. Can anyone confirm? After i changed my EMAIL to GMAIL on my GRAVATAR and STACK profile, no more gravatar (done that over a MONTH now!)